# Zend_Soap : How to define return type struct in doc block?

Tags: arrays, zend-framework, soap, struct, zend-soap

I have a Web service set up using Zend_Soap, and some public methods in that Web service.
The fact is i want to return a complex type.

For instance, if i want to return a bidimensional array, like a rowset of a table how should i specify the doc block?
This is one of my cases. I want to return an array each element having an int and two strings. Like:

```
[0] = {1 , NameA, StringA }
[1] = {4 , NameB, StringB }
[2] = {6 , NameC, StringC }
[3] = {9 , NameD, StringD }
```

How can i achieve this?
Then how can i make even more complex by, say, replace the 3rd field with another array of an int and a string?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.autodiscovery.html

With it you just have to define your complex type

```
class complexType {
/*put your definitions of class here*/

}
```

and put it in phpdoc like this

```
     /**
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return complexType
     */
    public function getSomething($id) {
```